# Coplanar codition

Tags: algebraic-geometry

My question is simple I want to verify two question. These question is started in Hartshorne book Proposition (IV.3.8).

Let $X$ be a projective variety in $\mathbb{P}^n$

1. the set $\{(p,q)\in X \times X | L_p \cap L_q \neq \emptyset\}$ is a closed set where $L_p$ is the tangent line to $X$ at $P$?
2. Fix point $p\in \mathbb{P}^n$, the set $\{q\in X | p\in L_q\}$ is a closed set?